# Overloaded operator () vs member function get()

Tags: c++, object, this, operator-keyword

So in my code I have

```
double Matrix::get(int i, int j){
     return data[i][j];
}

double Matrix::operator()(int i, int j){
      return data[i][j];
}
```

The problem is, outside the class I can call

```
Matrix A;
A(i,j)
```

Inside the class I don't know how the reference the object (A)
So that

```
Matrix::somefunction(){
    this(i,j)  ???
}
```

How would I reference the calling object?

Comment: `(*this)(i, j)` or `this->operator()(i, j)`.

Comment: operator()(i, j) is sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got very close:

```
(*this)(i,j)
```

Comment: Thanks! That frustratingly close haha

Answer (score 0):

You can also call like

```
    operator()(i,j);
```

or (as said)

```
    (*this)(i,j);
```